# Is it possible to create OSGI Service programmatically with Injections resolved

Tags: java, osgi, aem, apache-felix

Unfortunately, I could not find a way to create an osgi service programmatically with resolved references. It is a well known fact, that OSGi creates service as a singleton object. Owing to some reason, I need to create new service instances manually.

The case:

```
@Service(ICasualService.class)
@Component(immediate = true, label = "Casual Service")
public class CasualService implements ICasualService {

    @Reference
    private ConfigurationAdmin configurationAdmin;
}
```

Using Bundle Context I am able to register my service:

```
private BundleContext bundleContext;
ICasualService casualService = new CasualService();  
Dictionary props = new Properties();
bundleContext.registerService(ICasualService.class.getName(), casualService, props);
```

However, this way **configurationAdmin** is null in a new created service.

The question is whether it possible to create a new instance of the service programmatically?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:** Solution should work for Felix (OSGi implementation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a ComponentFactory to create instances of a component. See [this article at Vogella](http://blog.vogella.com/2017/02/13/control-osgi-ds-component-instances/).

Use this on the component you want to create programmatically:

```
@Component(factory="fipro.oneshot.factory")
```

Then in another component you can get the ComponentFactory:

```
@Reference(target = "(component.factory=fipro.oneshot.factory)")
    private ComponentFactory factory;
```

and create an instance from it:

```
ComponentInstance instance = this.factory.newInstance(null);
OneShot shooter = (OneShot) instance.getInstance();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. Moreover, 1. This way you can create new service with appropriate configuration parameters by passing them into this.factory.newInstance(Dictionary) method; 2. It creates new instances of service (in case .newInstance(null) it returns the same object each time).